# Get parsimonious to print useful error message for Sequence blocks

Tags: python, parsing, peg, parsimonious

I'm using parsimonious (python PEG parser library) to parse text that looks like this:

```
text = """
block block_name_0
{
    foo
}

block block_name_1
{
    bar
}

"""
```

It is a series of blocks with a simple body requirement (must be alphanum) that make up the whole text. Here's the grammar:

```
grammar = Grammar(r"""
file = block+
block = _ "block" _ alphanum _ start_brace _ block_body _ end_brace _
block_body = alphanum+
alphanum = ~"[_A-z0-9]+"
_ = ~"[\\n\\s]*"
start_brace = "{"
end_brace = "}"
""")

print (grammar.parse(text))
```

The problem I'm having is I get a useless error message if there's a parsing error in any block after the first one. To give an example, consider the following text:

```
text = """
block block_name_0
{
    !foo
}

block block_name_1
{
    bar
}

"""
```

This gives a useful error message:

```
[omitted stack trace]
  File "/lib/parsimonious/expressions.py", line 127, in match
    raise error
parsimonious.exceptions.ParseError: Rule 'block_body' didn't match at '!foo
}
```

However, if I have the following text:

```
text = """
block block_name_0
{
    foo
}

block block_name_1
{
    !bar
}

"""
```

I get this error:

```
  File "/lib/parsimonious/expressions.py", line 112, in parse
    raise IncompleteParseError(text, node.end, self)
parsimonious.exceptions.IncompleteParseError: Rule 'file' matched in its entirety, but it didn't consume all the text. The non-matching portion of the text begins with 'block block_name_1
{' (line 7, column 1).
```

It looks like it matches the first instances of the sequence (the first block), but when it fails on the second block it doesn't consider the whole thing as a failure, which is what I want it to do. I want it to give me a similar error as block 0 so I can know exactly what went wrong with the block, not just that the whole block couldn't be parsed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer for parsimonious but for good error reporting support I would suggest you to try [textX](https://github.com/igordejanovic/textX) or directly its underlying PEG parser [Arpeggio](https://github.com/igordejanovic/arpeggio) (disclaimer: I'm author of these libs).

Using textX:

```
from textx.metamodel import metamodel_from_str

grammar = """
Program: blocks+=Block ;

Block:
 'block' name=ID '{'
     body=Body
 '}'
;

Body: ID+ ;
"""

text = """
block block_name_0
{
    foo
}

block block_name_1
{
    !bar
}

"""

mm = metamodel_from_str(grammar)
program = mm.model_from_str(text)
```

textX/Arpeggio will parse as far as it can and pinpoint the exact location where the error is:

```
textx.exceptions.TextXSyntaxError:
   Expected ID at position (9, 5) => 'e_1 {     *!bar }  '.
```

With textX you also get AST for free so you can for example do:

```
for block in program.blocks:
    print(block.name, ':', block.body)
```

And for debugging/investigation purposes you also have a [nice visualization of grammars and models](http://igordejanovic.net/textX/visualization/).